# CKEditor bin/release folder not found

Tags: ckeditor

I downloaded ckeditor 4.5.3 Standard but it's missing bin/release/ folder and ckeditor.NET.dll file. I downloaded ckeditor from their official website.

I also downloaded the basic and full but I don't see the bin/release/ckeditor.NET.dll in it.

Please advise, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've downloaded CKEditor, but not the CKEditor.NET package, which is [further down on the downloads page](http://ckeditor.com/download#ckbuilder-col).

However, the CKEditor.NET package hasn't been updated since v3.6.6.2 in July 2014. It's unlikely to work with the latest version of CKEditor, which has made some significant changes to the API.

Comment: This answered my question, Thank you.